# Click action in push notification with firebase and react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already implement the push notification on my app and its working.
right now when someone click on the notification the app is opening.

In addition for this I want to do another thing when a user press on the notification:

**1. post request to the server(I want to keep a record that someone click on the notification).**

**2. open the app like now**

my question is how can I do that? I need to implement it on the server side or on the react native side?
If someone has tutorial of how to do it (**for android and iOS or even for one of them**) it will help a lot!

I was looking a lot but didn't find something which can help me.

Im adding my implement:

**on the server side:**

```
       public void sendNotification(String token,String msg)  {

    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    String registrationToken =token;

  // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    Message message = Message.builder()
            .setNotification(new com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification( null,msg))
            .setToken(registrationToken).setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder().setAps(Aps.builder().setSound("default").build()).build()).setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setSound("default").build()).build())
            .build();

    try {
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {

    }
}
```

**on react native:**
**for android:**

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private static int count = 0;
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message TITLE: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message BODY: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message DATA: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        String click_action= remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
//Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData());
    }
//This method is only generating push notification
    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody, Map<String, String> row) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());
        count++;
    }
 }
```

**on iOS:**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
   [FIRApp configure];
   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]  initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"**"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;

    }

  // Required to register for notifications
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
  {

    [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

     }
 // Required for the register event.
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
     {
      [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
       }
 // Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

  {
     [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    //NSLog(@"push-notification received: %@", notification)   
     }
  // Required for the registrationError event.
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
    }
  // Required for the localNotification event.
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
   {
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
    }
```

**when im getting token:**

```
  setNotification(userid){

   const version =  DeviceInfo.getUniqueID()
      firebase.app().onReady().then(app => { 
      const again=  AsyncStorage.getItem('deviceToken', (err, token) =>  {
      this.props.profileActions.updateLoginTrack()
       console.log("checkingTokenFromLogin",token)
       console.log('version', version)
       if(token==null)    {
      console.log("tokenNull")

    app.messaging().getToken()
    .then(fcmToken => {
      if (fcmToken) {
          console.log('fcmtokenApp', fcmToken)
          this.saveDeviceToken(fcmToken)
          //need to save in database too
          let deviceTokenData = {
            userId:       userid,
            deviceUniqueId:        version,
            deviceToken:         fcmToken,
          }
          this.props.profileActions.updateDeviceToken(deviceTokenData)

      } else {
        console.log('error with getting token')
      } 
    })


  }
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

the solution I found is

[right here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications)

I used only the function

```
getInitialNotification()
```

with this function you can trigger the notification when the app close.

If you want to to trigger the notification when the app is in the background you want use this function:

```
onNotificationOpened()
```

with this function I didn't use the listener(it didn't work for me), I only use this function in

```
componentDidMount
```

and not in

```
componentWillUnmount
```

hope it will help someone and save some time for you

Comment: I have a question, I'm developing two apps first of the user app and second to providers, in user app, I made some function to send order and saved into real-time database firebase t and in the second app I just retrieve the data from DB with a listener to get the new order as a real-time without refreshing the app, SO I want to when I send an order from user app to firebase I want to display a notify in the second app? How to handle these

Comment: @DevAS everything with firebase is about configuration and device token, you need first to do configuration in both apps, then connect your both apps to firebase console. you need that both app will have access to the same DB for getting the device token, you need to save the device tokens in your DB of the users that logged in to your app(this app should be the app you want to send the notification), in my case I'm sending the notification from my backend but im pretty sure you can do it from you app

Comment: @DevAS if you don't know how to send notification using firebase you should check out this link:
https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

or any other tutorial on youtube.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I can easily do this but the idea is I want to send notification from app to another app NOT in firebase console!

Comment: @DevAS I don’t think I have something in my mind for how to do it. I’ll recommend for you to search it or open a new post

Comment: i'm already adding it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140314/how-to-communicate-between-two-apps-using-the-same-firebase-database-in-react-na