# How to communicate between two Apps using the same firebase database in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two different apps using the same real-time database,

in the first app I'm sending an order contained some data field to save in DB and in another app I just add a listener

```
firebase.database().ref(`userOrder/${currentUser}/orders`).Orders.on("value", (snapshot) => {});
```

to retrieve the data on DB and it's work fine without any refresh cuz it's a Real-Time :D, so my question is when I send the data from the first app I want to display a **notification** in another app contain some data I send, 
I'm playing with Cloud Messaging and send some Test message from the console Firebase and its work and receive very well, so how to handle that in the code

here is my Send Order Code:

```
//import liraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "../Style/styles";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
import { View, Text, TextInput, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker'

// create a component
const currentdate = new Date();
const datetime =
    currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + currentdate.getDate() + " " +
    currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes()

class Order extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: null,
            datetime: datetime,
            imageOfPrblem: '',
            Incomplete: 'Incomplete',
            providerId: this.props.navigation.getParam('providerId'),
            providerName: this.props.navigation.getParam('providerName'),
            providerService: this.props.navigation.getParam('providerService'),
        }
        this.initialState = { ...this.state }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        this.setState({ userId });
    }

    handleOrder = () => {
        const { nameOfProblem, providerName, datetime, description, Price, userId, imageOfPrblem, providerId, providerService, Incomplete } = this.state;

        const PushData = firebase.database().ref("request/" + providerId + "/" + userId + "/orders/");


        let file = imageOfPrblem.uri;
        const path = "Img_" + imageOfPrblem.fileName;
        console.log("@IMAGE", path);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref("users/" + userId + "/UserImageOrders/" + path);

        newOrderRef = PushData.push({
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
            providerName: providerName,
            statusInfo: Incomplete,
            providerService: providerService,
            nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
            description: description,
            Price: Price,
            datetime: datetime
        });

        if (file) {
            let keyG = newOrderRef.key; // Key Generated with .push()
            PushData.child(keyG).update({
                id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
                providerName: providerName,
                datetime: datetime,
                providerService: providerService,
                nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
                description: description,
                Price: Price,
                imageOfPrblem: imageOfPrblem
            })
            ref.put(file).then(() => {
                this.setState(this.initialState);
                alert("Order Sent with Image.")
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
            });
        } else {
            newOrderRef.then(() => {
                this.setState(this.initialState);
                alert("Order Sent.")
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                }, 1500);
            });
        }
    }
    handleOrderForUser = () => {
        const { nameOfProblem, datetime, description, Price, userId, imageOfPrblem, providerService, providerName, Incomplete } = this.state;

        const PushData = firebase.database().ref("userOrder/" + userId + "/orders/");


        let file = imageOfPrblem.uri;
        const path = "Img_" + imageOfPrblem.fileName;
        console.log("@IMAGE", path);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref("users/" + userId + "/UserImageOrders/" + path);

        newOrderRef = PushData.push({
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
            providerName: providerName,
            statusInfo: Incomplete,
            providerService: providerService,
            nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
            description: description,
            Price: Price,
            datetime: datetime
        });

        if (file) {
            let keyG = newOrderRef.key; // Key Generated with .push()
            PushData.child(keyG).update({
                id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
                providerName: providerName,
                datetime: datetime,
                providerService: providerService,
                nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
                description: description,
                Price: Price,
                imageOfPrblem: imageOfPrblem
            })
            ref.put(file).then(() => {
                this.setState(this.initialState);
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
            });
        } else {
            newOrderRef.then(() => {
                this.setState(this.initialState);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                }, 1500);
            });
        }
    }

    handleImages = () => {
        const options = {
            title: "Select Images!",
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: "images"
            }
        };
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
            if (response.uri) {
                this.setState({ imageOfPrblem: response });
            }
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log("User cancelled image picker");
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
                alert(response.customButton);
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { nameOfProblem, description, imageOfPrblem, providerId, datetime, providerName, Price } = this.state;
        // const { getParam } = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
        // const providerId = getParam('providerId');
        // const providerName = getParam('providerName');
        return (

            <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={70}>
                    <View style={[styles.container, { marginTop: 20 }]}>
                        <Text>Send Order To: {JSON.stringify(providerName)}, ID:{JSON.stringify(providerId)}</Text>

                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder="Name of Problem"
                            value={nameOfProblem}
                            onChangeText={(nameOfProblem) => this.setState({ nameOfProblem })}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            returnKeyLabel="next"
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder="Price"
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            value={Price}
                            onChangeText={(Price) => this.setState({ Price })}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            returnKeyLabel="next"
                        />
                        <DatePicker
                            style={{ width: 200 }}
                            date={datetime}
                            mode="datetime"
                            placeholder="select date"
                            format="YYYY-MM-DD H:mm a"
                            minDate="2019-02-01"
                            maxDate="2023-1-1"
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            customStyles={{
                                dateIcon: {
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    left: 0,
                                    top: 4,
                                    marginLeft: 0
                                },
                                dateInput: {
                                    marginLeft: 36
                                }
                            }}
                            onDateChange={datetime => this.setState({ datetime })}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            style={[styles.textInput, {
                                borderRadius: 5,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 120,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                padding: 10,
                                marginTop: 8
                            }]}
                            placeholder="Description"
                            multiline={true}
                            numberOfLines={12}
                            textAlignVertical="top"
                            value={description}
                            onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description })}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            returnKeyLabel="next"
                        />

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleImages}>
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: "#DBDBDB",
                                    borderRadius: 100,
                                    alignSelf: "center",
                                    margin: 10,
                                    paddingBottom: 2,
                                    width: 120,
                                    height: 120
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        zIndex: 1,
                                        fontSize: 40,
                                        top: 67,
                                        color: "#1567d3",
                                        left: 99
                                    }}
                                >
                                    +
                                </Text>
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: imageOfPrblem.uri }}
                                    style={[styles.uploadAvatar, { borderRadius: 100 }]}
                                    resizeMode="cover"
                                />

                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: "#1567d3" }]}
                            onPress={() => { this.handleOrder(); this.handleOrderForUser(); }}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 18 }}>Send</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}
export default Order;
```

Comment: You need to use cloud function for sending notification to another device when send data from first device!

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya  Exactly!